# npm ERR! missing script: serve

Tags: node.js, docker

Getting error while starting the docker container. I am using nodemon to listen to the file changes.

DockerFile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

Package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "nodemon": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "nodemon index.js",
        "start": "node index.js"
    }
}
```

build command

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t test/nodeapp1 .
```

cmdLine docker cmd ->

```
docker run -p 3000:8080 -v /app/node_modules -v pwd:/app test/nodeapp1.
```

Iam new to docker, and not able to figure out the cause.

Comment: how you are building the docker container @amruta

Comment: please add the errors and nodemon should be a global dependency right

Comment: looks like your build command is  not proper what is .dev

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in your dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV HOME=/home/node/app
ENV PATH="/home/node/.npm-global/bin:${PATH}"

USER node

RUN npm install -g nodemon


RUN mkdir -p ${HOME}
WORKDIR ${HOME}

ADD package.json ${HOME}

RUN cd ${HOME} && npm install

CMD [ "npm" ,"run", "serve" ]
```

Build the docker container

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t prac/nodeApp .
```

Run the docker container

```
docker run -p 3000:8080 -v /app/node_modules -v pwd:/app prac/nodeApp
```

Comment: I changed the workdir to a new value and it worked. not sure y it didn't worked with /app

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/dir'

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm" ,"run", "serve" ]

Comment: I just realized, that my WORKDIR is /dir , but volume is app, the lastest package.json is always copied to app, but if I change volume to dir, i am getting the same error.

Comment: can you try the above version if it helps

Comment: The workdir in your code snippet is different from the volume, I have the same thing dir and app, my question is if workdir and volume are same why it is not working.
I tried your code, COPY . ${HOME} command is missing from docker file. If I add that it works.

Comment: and please add the build command too in your question it will make the question more clear

Comment: Getting the same error now.
npm ERR! missing script: serve

Answer (score 0):

Changing the WORKDIR to a new value worked.

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/dir'

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm" ,"run", "serve" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker run -v` options are wrong.  You probably actually meant to write

```sh
docker run ... -v $PWD:/app ...
docker run ... -v $(pwd):/app ...
```

to use the current directory (from the `PWD` environment variable or from the `pwd` command, respectively) as a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

I tend to not recommend this pattern, especially for Node applications where the host dependencies are minimal and you're not interacting much with other containers.  It's probably easier to just install Node locally (if you don't already have it) and do live development against that; when you want to use Docker to deploy your application, use the version you've `COPY`ed into the image, and don't separately use a `-v` option to inject your code over it.